# Is it possible to use Spring Security (3.1.X) to get LDAP information on a user other that the one authenticated against?

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I use Spring Security to authenticate a user against an Active Directory server.  A CustomUserContext is also injected into the ldapAuthenticationProvider bean to provide access to additional LDAP attributes.  Everything works quite well. I have no problem pulling whatever I want from the authenticated user.

The issue I have is that I want to retrieve some attributes, most specifically the email address, from the Active Directory server on a user other than the user that is logged in.  Is it possible to achieve this by leveraging what I already have, or is my only option to use a totally separate method to access LDAP attributes from a different user?

*[edit]*
**Configuration follows**

security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://xxxx.xxxx.xxx:389" />
    <property name="base" value="dc=corp,dc=global,dc=xxxxx,dc=com" />
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=lna.authquery,OU=LDAPGroups,OU=NorthAmerica,DC=corp,DC=global,DC=xxxxx,DC=com" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx" />
    <property name="pooled" value="true" />
    <!-- AD Specific Setting for avoiding the partial exception error -->
    <property name="referral" value="follow" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
                    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(member={0})" />
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <!-- Settings below convert the adds the prefix ROLE_ to roles returned from AD -->
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
       <bean class="net.xxxx.xxxxx.utilities.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <sec:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' 
                    default-target-url="/home.html" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" />
</sec:http>
```

CustomeUserDetails.java

```
package net.xxxx.xxxx.utilities;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

public class CustomUserDetails extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1416132138315457558L;

     // extra instance variables
       final String fullname;
       final String email;
       final String title;

       public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
             boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
             Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String fullname,
             String email, String title) {

           super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked, authorities);

           this.fullname = fullname;
           this.email = email;
           this.title = title;
       }

       public String getFullname() {
           return this.fullname;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return this.email;
       }

       public String getTitle() {
           return this.title;
       }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsContextMapper.java

```
package net.xxxx.xxxxx.utilities;

import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
            String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        String fullname = "";
        String email = "";
        String title = "";

        Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes();
        try {
            fullname = (String) attributes.get("displayName").get(); 
            email = (String) attributes.get("mail").get(); 
            title = (String) attributes.get("title").get(); 
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CustomUserDetails details = new CustomUserDetails(username, "", true, true, true, true, authorities, fullname, email, title);
        return details;
    }

    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {

    }

}
```

Comment: You can probably just add some extra Spring LDAP calls to load the information you want, but it's not really possible to suggest a strategy without knowing what you already have and more details on where the additional information is and what the access permissions for it are.

Comment: @LukeTaylor valid point. Included the code.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted/closed as it seems like a pretty specific "Here's what I've done, how do I achieve X" question (particularly now that you've added the code). You should be able to extend your `CustomUserDetailsContextMapper` to make use of the `ContextSource` and perform the additional queries you need using Spring LDAP directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Bill what you've done is great, though there is actually an easier way. Instead of resorting to the `LdapTemplate`, just use the beans you've already registered for `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` and `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch`. This way you can get the same `UserDetails` object which also has the authorities populated and reuses your existing code for your `net.xxxx.xxxxx.utilities.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper`.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Split out the beens you need to inject as named beans and use `ref` attributes for the properties and `constructor-arg`s (`DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator`, `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch`, `net.xxxx.xxxxx.utilities.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper`).
2. In your `LdapDao` inject references to:

   - `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch` - `userSearch`
   - `DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator` - `authPop`
   - `net.xxxx.xxxxx.utilities.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper` - `userMapper`
3. Add the following method to your `LdapDao`:

.

```java
public UserDetails getUserDetails(final String username) {
    try {
        DirContextOperations ctx = userSearch.searchForUser(username);
        return userMapper.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username,
                authPop.getGrantedAuthorities(ctx, username));
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call `getUserDetails(String)` to get the same object you do when retrieving the currently logged in context, and can use the same code etc.

Comment: Another advantage is you won't need to move your `security-config.xml` file.

Answer (score 7):

I finally did end up figuring out how to do this. I'm answering this in case it helps someone else who needs to do this.  I'd be surprised if I'm the only one.

First I had to move my `security-config.xml` file out of the WEB-INF structure and put it under the spring resources directory.  The `contextSource` bean I was able to reuse.  However I could not reuse the `CustomUserDetailsContextMapper.java` nor the `CustomUserDetails.java` class as they were too specific to Spring security and not to just retrieving LDAP data from an unauthenticated user.

I ended up writing a separate class for the LDAP access that had the common `contextSource` autowired in.  That class is below.

**LdapDao.java**

```
package net.xxxxx.xxx.dao;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class LdapDao {

    LdapTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public LdapDao(LdapContextSource contextSource) {
        template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, String> getUserAttributes(String username) {
        Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String objectClass = "samAccountName=" + username;
        LinkedList<Map<String, String>> list = (LinkedList<Map<String, String>>) template.search("", objectClass, new UserAttributesMapper());
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            // Should only return one item
            results = list.get(0);
        }
        return results;
    }

    private class UserAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws javax.naming.NamingException {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String fullname = (String) attributes.get("displayName").get(); 
            String email = (String) attributes.get("mail").get(); 
            String title = (String) attributes.get("title").get();

            map.put("fullname", fullname);
            map.put("email", email);
            map.put("title", title);
            return map;
        }
    }   
}
```